# pca - which eigenvector corresponds to which eigenvalue

Tags: r, eigenvector

I am to do as follows:
I have a set of Vektors v1-vn
For these, I need the covariance matrix (which I get while doing a pca).
I also need the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of the covariance matrix.
The eigenvalues I sort in descending order and then I sort the eigenvectors according to their corresponding eigenvalues.
After that I multiply v1 with the first of the eigenvectors, v2 with the second and so on.
I return the skalar which I get in this way.

Is there any simple way in R to see which eigenvalue corresponds to which eigenvector?

Comment: adding a reproducible example would be more helpful

Comment: Have you tried `princomp`? It does everything for you.

Comment: I have tried princomp, it does the pca for me (so does prcomp) but it seems to be a bit more tricky to get the eigenvectors, let alone the corresponding eigenvalues.

Comment: What I mean is, as far as I know: sdev returns the eigenvalues while rotation returns the eigenvectors, but how do I know which eigenvalue belongs to which eigenvector?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the result of `prcomp` directly.  It sorts the eigenvalues from biggest to smallest.

```
 p <- prcomp(USArrests, scale=T)
```

For appropriate values of `i`, the eigenvalue is `p$sdev[i]^2`, with eigenvector `p$rotation[,i]`

Comment: so p$sdef[1]^2 would be the biggest eigenvalue, with eigenvector p$rotation[,1]?

Comment: However, the eigenvalues do not exactly seem to be sorted